# How do I extract the time-of-day from a date in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL database of dates and times, but they are combined into a single value (called time). I would like to determine the number of entries per every hour, but I cannot figure out how to do this.
If I do:

```
Select time from time_table
```

The result I get is:

```
2016-05-13 07:23:23
2016-05-13 07:34:34
2016-05-14 07:21:00
2016-05-14 09:42:43
```

What I would like is either:

```
07:23:23
07:34:34
07:21:00
09:42:43
```

which I can sort to get:

```
07:21:00
07:23:23
07:34:34
09:42:43
```

Or, ultimately, I'd like to get counts:

```
07-08: 3
08-09: 0
09-10: 1
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are uisng.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `time` column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract only Time from a DateTime field in Oracle SQL Developer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104414/how-to-extract-only-time-from-a-datetime-field-in-oracle-sql-developer)

Comment: Where should a time like 08:00:00 be counted - in 07-08 or in 08-09? Or in both?

Answer (score 1):

Time-of-day can be extracted from a value of DATE datatype by subtracting the truncation of that value:

```
select time - trunc(time) from.....
```

This will return a fractional number, >= 0 and < 1, representing a fraction of a day. To convert it to hour: multiply by 24.

For example, it is ~ 8:08 pm where I am right now. Then:

```
select 24 * (sysdate - trunc(sysdate)) as result from dual;

    RESULT
----------
20.1566667
```

So now, if I want to know the hour, I can take `trunc()` again. Earlier I truncated a date; now the result is a number and I truncate a number.

Putting it all together (the first part generates the whole numbers from 0 to 23):

```
with h ( hr ) as (select level - 1 from dual connect by level <= 24)
select h.hr, count(tt.time) as ct
from   h left outer join time_table tt on h.hr = trunc(24 * (tt.time - trunc(tt.time)))
group by h.hr
order by hr  -- optional
;
```

You can format the "hour" column differently, although I don't see the point; my solution will show 8 where you show 08-09. Both have the same information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution with two sub-queries, one to generate a complete list of hours and one to generate a list of numbers in the target table. An outer join is necessary to produce zero counts for hours with no matches.

Note that bucket labels such as 7-8, 8-9 imply double counting, so I've ignored that in favour of single hours.

```
SQL> select * from t42
  2  /

        ID TCOL
---------- -------------------
         1 2016-05-13 07:23:23
         2 2016-05-13 07:34:34
         3 2016-05-14 07:21:00
         4 2016-05-14 09:42:43

SQL> with hrs as (select level-1 as hr
  2               from dual
  3               connect by level <= 24 )
  4     , t as (select to_number(to_char(tcol, 'HH24')) as hr
  5             from t42)
  6  select hrs.hr
  7            , count(t.hr)
  8  from hrs
  9       left outer join t
 10        on hrs.hr = t.hr
 11  where hrs.hr between 7 and 9
 12  group by hrs.hr
 13  order by hrs.hr
 14  /

        HR COUNT(T.HR)
---------- -----------
         7           3
         8           0
         9           1

SQL>
```

This solution assumes the time column is an Oracle date datatype. If it's a string then either casting it to a date first or applying a `substr()` would work.

Answer (score 0):

this will help you to solve you problem taken from 
[Counting number of records hour by hour between two dates in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714680/counting-number-of-records-hour-by-hour-between-two-dates-in-oracle)

```
SELECT 
       trunc(time ,'HH'), 
       count(*) 
     FROM 
       time_table
     WHERE 
       time > trunc(SYSDATE -2) 
     group by trunc(time ,'HH');
```

Result

2016-11-29 09:00:00.0  |    8     |

Comment: This approach sees the time 09:15:00 on different days as falling within different "one-hour intervals". The OP specifically wanted to discard the date portion and count everything between 7 am and 8 am (for example) together, even from different dates.

Comment: so in order to calculate count everything between 7 am and 8 am even from different dates just remove "WHERE clause" .
e.g final query would be like this
SELECT 
       trunc(DTIME ,'HH'), 
       count(*) 
     FROM 
       time_table
     group by trunc(DTIME ,'HH');