# sql query to count person in each hour separately

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which has theses fields:

```
id | person_id | start_time | end_time | status
```

I want to get number of people which exists in each hour in a specific day, something like below pseudo code:

```
select count(person) from table where dow of end_time=day and end_time >= hour and start_time < hour+1 for hour in working hours of organization and day is a certain day of week
```

If it would be possible to have a temporary table which consists of hours of a day may be the following solution is a solution:

```
select t.h, count(s.id)
from
session s cross join (temperoray table with one column of hours in a day as t)
where
s.start_time < (t.h + 1) and s.end_time > t.h
group by
t.h
```

But I do not know a command which could create a temporary table as I needed.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714680/counting-number-of-records-hour-by-hour-between-two-dates-in-oracle) which is very similar to what I want but all of its solution is based on `group by` which I do not think makes any sense in my case because parts of each group has common items, e.g., a person could count as person in hour 11 and person in hour 12 and 13.

I hope that I can find a way that gets me a table like this:

```
hour     |number of persons
10       |2
11       |0
12       |3
13       |1
...
```

Notice that it may possible to have some day with zero number of persons.

### Example:

```
  id  | status |            start_time            |             end_time             | branch_id | person_id | session_type 
------+--------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------
 2675 | FI     | 2018-04-23 10:30:50.939693+04:30 | 2018-04-23 12:31:39.340692+04:30 |         1 |      1085 | IN
 2676 | FI     | 2018-04-23 11:47:06.683374+04:30 | 2018-04-23 13:23:52.659714+04:30 |         1 |      2722 | IN
 2677 | FI     | 2018-04-23 11:47:59.341765+04:30 | 2018-04-23 13:25:46.339266+04:30 |         1 |      2721 | IN
 2678 | FI     | 2018-04-23 11:58:34.854222+04:30 | 2018-04-23 13:25:55.08795+04:30  |         1 |      2723 | IN
 2679 | FI     | 2018-04-23 12:27:58.817234+04:30 | 2018-04-23 13:12:28.278699+04:30 |         1 |      2724 | IN
 2680 | FI     | 2018-04-23 12:30:36.552407+04:30 | 2018-04-23 12:30:54.088159+04:30 |         1 |      2725 | IN
 2681 | FI     | 2018-04-23 14:55:50.886725+04:30 | 2018-04-23 16:08:27.076629+04:30 |         1 |        25 | IN
 2682 | FI     | 2018-04-23 15:06:30.443347+04:30 | 2018-04-23 15:52:20.128546+04:30 |         1 |      2653 | IN
 2683 | FI     | 2018-04-23 15:21:57.979387+04:30 | 2018-04-23 16:16:09.289267+04:30 |         1 |      2580 | IN
 2684 | FI     | 2018-04-23 15:26:18.057999+04:30 | 2018-04-23 16:02:44.704133+04:30 |         1 |      2726 | IN
 2685 | FI     | 2018-04-23 16:50:10.2957+04:30   | 2018-04-23 17:23:01.732404+04:30 |         1 |      2727 | IN
 2686 | FI     | 2018-04-23 16:52:28.474299+04:30 | 2018-04-23 17:23:51.013318+04:30 |         1 |      2728 | IN
 2687 | FI     | 2018-04-23 16:58:05.796563+04:30 | 2018-04-23 17:33:03.259335+04:30 |         1 |      1646 | IN
 2688 | FI     | 2018-04-23 17:50:02.738009+04:30 | 2018-04-23 18:43:27.152203+04:30 |         1 |      2729 | IN
 2689 | FI     | 2018-04-23 18:47:12.19468+04:30  | 2018-04-23 19:25:46.606731+04:30 |         1 |      2730 | IN
 2690 | FI     | 2018-04-23 19:18:32.922065+04:30 | 2018-04-23 20:11:26.703693+04:30 |         1 |      2408 | IN
 2691 | FI     | 2018-04-23 19:18:53.133712+04:30 | 2018-04-23 19:56:47.702305+04:30 |         1 |      2409 | IN
 2692 | FI     | 2018-04-23 19:21:00.348889+04:30 | 2018-04-23 20:24:25.882451+04:30 |         1 |      2731 | IN
 2693 | FI     | 2018-04-23 19:30:05.908247+04:30 | 2018-04-23 20:12:36.627888+04:30 |         1 |      2591 | IN
 2694 | FI     | 2018-04-23 19:36:02.700379+04:30 | 2018-04-23 20:13:35.146002+04:30 |         1 |      2732 | IN
 2695 | FI     | 2018-04-23 19:50:15.13214+04:30  | 2018-04-23 20:09:37.168147+04:30 |         1 |      2491 | IN
 2696 | FI     | 2018-04-23 19:51:54.754169+04:30 | 2018-04-23 20:09:59.029376+04:30 |         1 |      2733 | IN
 2697 | FI     | 2018-04-23 19:53:13.529475+04:30 | 2018-04-23 20:09:49.229139+04:30 |         1 |      2734 | IN
 2698 | FI     | 2018-04-23 19:59:27.70488+04:30  | 2018-04-23 20:21:47.862433+04:30 |         1 |      1762 | IN
 2699 | FI     | 2018-04-23 19:59:57.86605+04:30  | 2018-04-23 20:22:05.171377+04:30 |         1 |      1761 | IN
 2700 | FI     | 2018-04-23 20:24:21.212784+04:30 | 2018-04-23 20:47:31.854373+04:30 |         1 |      2735 | IN
 2701 | FI     | 2018-04-23 21:58:57.308547+04:30 | 2018-04-23 22:43:20.075321+04:30 |         1 |      1705 | IN
 2702 | FI     | 2018-04-23 21:59:44.974384+04:30 | 2018-04-23 22:43:45.946989+04:30 |         1 |      1704 | IN
 2703 | FI     | 2018-04-23 22:10:20.991216+04:30 | 2018-04-23 22:40:51.16409+04:30  |         1 |      2711 | IN
```

And I which to get results for this day as below:

```
hour   | number
10     | 1
11     | 4
12     | 6
13     | 4
14     | 1
15     | 4
16     | 6
17     | 4
18     | 2
19     | 11
20     | 10
21     | 2
22     | 3
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?that really help

Comment: I don't see how this could be done without counting number of persons (ie using group by).

Comment: @DanielVaca I put some examples of my data in a certain date, and manually compute the number of people in each hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the generate_series from [D-Shih's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50118777/1607951) I get the following solutions.

This first solution shows all hours when at least one person was working.

```
select Hour, count(1) as "Users"
from generate_series(1,24) as gs (Hour)
join Log as l
  on  date_part('hour',l.TimeFrom) <= gs.Hour
  and date_part('hour',l.TimeTo) >= gs.Hour
group by Hour
order by Hour;
```

If you also need the hours when nobody was working, use a `left join`.
This requires a change to the `count()` to only count when a record is found.

```
select Hour, count(case when l.UserId is not null then 1 end) as "Users"
from generate_series(1,24) as gs (Hour)
left join Log as l
  on  date_part('hour',l.TimeFrom) <= gs.Hour
  and date_part('hour',l.TimeTo) >= gs.Hour
group by Hour
order by Hour;
```

See [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/014e8/15) for some example data and output.

Comment: Your answer seems correct but left join does not work for me and I get just the rows that match in both tables and no rows with null value of the second table. Is it possible because I do not let some values of the second table be null?

Comment: Are you using the left joined table in your where clause by any chance? Doing so means that a record *must* be found in the second table or the where clause cannot be validated. This implicitly turns a left outer join into an inner join. Like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/014e8/18

Comment: Yes, your guess is true, finally, this query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b8444/8 works for me.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correct

you need to use `generate_series` function to create 24 hour then `left join` it.

You can add some condition on `Where` clause.

Get by **Hour**

```
SELECT    gs.hours, 
          Sum( 
          CASE 
                    WHEN start_time IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
                    WHEN end_time IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
          END ) AS "count" 
FROM      ( 
                 SELECT hours 
                 FROM   Generate_series(1,24) AS gs(hours) ) gs 
LEFT JOIN 
          ( 
                 SELECT *, 
                        Generate_series(start_time::timestamp, end_time::timestamp, '1 hours') invhour
                 FROM   t )t 
ON        gs.hours = To_char(t.invhour,'HH24')::integer 
GROUP BY  gs.hours
```

Get by **Hour** and **Date**

```
SELECT    To_char(t.invhour,'yyyy-MM-dd') AS "dates", 
          gs.hours, 
          Sum( 
          CASE 
                    WHEN start_time IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
                    WHEN end_time IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
          END ) AS "count" 
FROM      ( 
                 SELECT hours 
                 FROM   Generate_series(1,24) AS gs(hours) ) gs 
LEFT JOIN 
          ( 
                 SELECT *, 
                        Generate_series(start_time::timestamp, end_time::timestamp, '1 hours') invhour
                 FROM   t )t 
ON        gs.hours = To_char(t.invhour,'HH24')::integer 
GROUP BY  gs.hours, 
          to_char(t.invhour,'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/717fa/1*

[generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a set for the 24 hours, then do a left join and a group by hour.

Someone here has suggested using generate_series in a subquery, but personally I think recursive ctes are a little nicer for creating ranges. This way you can keep the series set outside the main query, making it a little easier to understand and maintain.

```
; WITH RECURSIVE Hours AS 
(
   SELECT 1 AS hour
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT hour + 1 FROM Hours WHERE Hour < 24
)

SELECT hour, COUNT(person_id)
FROM Hours
LEFT JOIN T on hour BETWEEN extract(hour from start_time) AND extract(hour from end_time)
GROUP BY hour
ORDER BY hour
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/717fa/12/0

Comment: This is wonderful, would there be a way to account for employees that  log out and then back in within the same hour so that the query doesn't count them twice ?

Comment: @honey_badgerzz that sounds like you want to group the result. Presumably if you group by EmployeeId and by Hour that would give you what youre after.
You can do that by having your employee logins in a sub query before joining to it

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [article](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/statements/create_temporary_table) which walks through creating a Temp table in PostgreSQL (I am a SQL server person).

Have one column which is the hours of the day and I think your method of joining it to your table would work.

It also depends on your data in that table too. Can you provide a top 1 row data to get an idea of how it looks like? You might not even need the temp table.